# datagrid will render the data twice

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I used the DataGrid to display data, but I found a wizard case that will render the data twice.

Details are below:

1. Click the "browse" button, then it will send a request to the server;
2. Server returns the JSON format data
3. Use the alert to debug in DataGrid like:

   ```
   loadFilter: function (data) {
               //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
               alert(data.rows.length);
               if (data.rows.length == 0) {
                   //alert('读取有问题，重新填充');
                   $(selector).datagrid("load");
                   return $(selector).datagrid("getData");
               }
               return data;
           },
   ```
4. The alert then occurs twice, one by one.

Comment: If i replace the loadFilter with below code,it works, not request the server all times.

Comment: loadFilter: function (data) {                                       
                    if (data.rows.length == 0) {                                                                       
                        return false;
                    }
                    return data;
                },